# Linux IP forwarding; source IP is changed?

Tags: linux, networking, docker

Apologies for the vague title of this post, I wasn't quite sure what to call this behaviour.

I have set up a virtual network topology like so:

```
+------------+                  +------------+
| host1      |                  | router     |
| 172.41.1.1 | <---- net1 ----> | 172.41.2.1 |                  +------------+
+------------+  (172.41.0.0/16) | 172.42.2.1 | <---- net2 ----> | host2      |
                                +------------+  (172.42.0.0/16) | 172.42.1.1 |
                                                                +------------+
```

These "nodes" are in fact containers, and the networks are [Docker networks](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/#user-defined-networks). (Additionally, `net1` is a tunnel network, but I have elided this as I think it is irrelevant for the problem I am seeing.)

When I run `ping 172.42.1.2` on `host1`, I do not see responses. Running `tcpdump -i eth1 -n` on `router` (`eth1` is the interface for `net2`), I see what looks to me like correct packets being forwarded:

```
15:06:09.180072 IP 172.41.1.1 > 172.42.1.1: ICMP echo request, id 1, seq 14, length 64
15:06:10.181545 IP 172.41.1.1 > 172.42.1.1: ICMP echo request, id 1, seq 15, length 64
15:06:11.182521 IP 172.41.1.1 > 172.42.1.1: ICMP echo request, id 1, seq 16, length 64
15:06:12.184381 IP 172.41.1.1 > 172.42.1.1: ICMP echo request, id 1, seq 17, length 64
```

However, on `host2` I see the following:

```
15:06:58.257789 IP 172.42.0.1 > 172.42.1.1: ICMP echo request, id 1, seq 63, length 64
15:06:58.257811 IP 172.42.1.1 > 172.42.0.1: ICMP echo reply, id 1, seq 63, length 64
15:06:59.259254 IP 172.42.0.1 > 172.42.1.1: ICMP echo request, id 1, seq 64, length 64
15:06:59.259282 IP 172.42.1.1 > 172.42.0.1: ICMP echo reply, id 1, seq 64, length 64
```

That is, the source IP of the packets appears to be changed to the network address of `net2`: `172.42.0.1`. **Why would this happen?**

Comment: The IP addressing scheme you are using is quite confusing. Also, the addresses in TCPDump outputs are odd, some of them are not mentioned in the network diagram. Please give more precise information on addressing.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen Which unmentioned address are you referring to?

Comment: `172.42.1.1` and `172.42.0.1`.

Comment: Please provide the output from `route -r` on host1, router and host2.  My guess, host2 doesn't know where to respond because of missing route.

Comment: Check the configuration of whatever machine substituted its own address for the source address. That machine was configured to do NAT for some reason, possibly a very good one, possibly not.

Answer (score 1):

Just so you are aware, 172.41.0.0/16 and 172.42.0.0/16 are not private addresses (RFC1918). The 20-bit private net is 172.16.0.0/12 which gives a range of 172.16.0.0 to 172.31.255.255. This shouldn't be the cause of this problem, but may cause you grief if you expect to be able to access all hosts on the internet.

The question is a bit light on information regarding your router config, but my first guess would be that you have packet mangling (NAT) rules on your router. Do `iptables -F` and try again.